# How to resample a dataframe in pandas and apply a weighted average?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, indexed by time, with 2 columns: `price` and `quantity`.

I want to construct a new series that is the weighted average price over 15 minute intervals, weighted by quantity.

Here is my dataframe's head:

```
                          price  quantity
ts                                        
2020-06-10 15:56:34+00:00  203.0       400
2020-06-10 15:57:10+00:00  203.0      1300
2020-06-10 15:57:11+00:00  203.0      1100
2020-06-10 15:57:13+00:00  203.0      3000
2020-06-10 15:57:14+00:00  203.0       700
```

Here is my best attempt:

```py
def resample_method(x):
    return np.average(x.price, weights=x.quantity)

df.resample("15T").apply(resample_method)
```

While the above code expresses my intent (I believe), I get the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'Series' object has no attribute 'price'
```

Comment: When you use apply, the default axis is on columns therefore apply access each column at a time.  So, when the 'price' column is called, the 'quantity' column is not available.  What you need to do his caculate each rows weighted prices, then resample 15T on that weighted price column.

Answer (score 0):

So as pointed out by @Scott Boston in a comment, when using `resample`, both columns are not accessible at the same time. One trick could be to append the column quantity to the index because the index are accessible with each column.

```
# note I used '1T' instead of 15T like you but simple change in the method
dfr = (df.set_index('quantity', append=True)
         .resample('1T', level=0) # the datetime index is the level=0 
         .apply(lambda x: np.average(x, weights=x.index.get_level_values(1))) #quantity is on level=1
      )
print (dfr) #result not really interesting here it works
                           price
ts                              
2020-06-10 15:56:00+00:00  203.0
2020-06-10 15:57:00+00:00  203.0
```